# Issue while inverting Marklogic map

Tags: xquery, marklogic

While inverting MarkLogic map, the keys & values get swapped, however the values get de-duplicated. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you trying to get a unique set of the sequences that are contained in both maps, where a new map contains entries where if the entry values were the same in both maps? If so, do the keys matter or would you have a
 preference for which map's keys to use in the result? A simplified example of inputs and desired outputs would make it easier to understand what you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't. MarkLogic `map:map` is a hash table, so keys are unique. When inverting it will merge keys of duplicate values:

```
-map:new((
  map:entry("a", (1, 2)),
  map:entry("b", (2, 3))
))
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might just want to iterate the `map:map`.

HTH!

Comment: What I want to achieve is: I have two maps and I want to perform SET operators like intersection and difference based on values present in both of the maps. Now since set operators work on keys only, I am inverting both the maps before doing intersection, but this way I am losing data because of de-duplication. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `$map1 * $map2`? See also: http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/im-a-map

Comment: Yes I'm using -> (-$map1) * (-$map2) since I need to perform intersection on basis of values, however the data changes as soon as I invert values to keys, since those values(i.e keys post inversion) are now de-duplicated which I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you update the question to provide a small example?